# PHP won't load pdo_mysql extension on Fedora 25

Tags: php, mysql, linux, pdo, fedora-25

After a little toying around with my FreePBX install on F25, I seem to have broken it, and can't get pdo_mysql to load:

```
[root@freepbx-localdomain freepbx] # /usr/bin/env php -m | grep -i pdo
PDO
pdo_sqlite
```

FreePBX's `./install` errors out appropriately:

```
Checking if Asterisk is running and we can talk to it as the 'asterisk' user...Done
Preliminary checks done. Starting FreePBX Installation
Checking if this is a new install...Yes (No /etc/amportal.conf file detected)
Database Root installation checking credentials and permissions..Error!
Invalid Database Permissions. The error was: could not find driver
```

Lastly, pdo_mysql is in the /etc/php.d directory:

```
[root@freepbx-localdomain php.d] # ls *pdo_mysql*
30-pdo_mysql.ini
```

I'm struggling here, and about to do a clean CentOS install (and not run it on Fedora Workstation, which wasn't the best idea). Ideas?

Edit: While supposedly php.ini is no longer used to load extensions, I did try it anyways, adding:

```
extension="pdo.so"
extension="pdo_mysql.so"
```

And now...

```
[root@freepbx-localdomain freepbx] # /usr/bin/env php -m | grep -i pdo
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/pdo.so' - /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/pdo.so: undefined symbol: zend_new_interned_string in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/pdo_mysql.so' - /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/pdo_mysql.so: undefined symbol: mysqlnd_allocator in Unknown on line 0
PDO
pdo_sqlite
```

Comment: 1) There is no Fedora 25 ... do you mean "Rawhide under development" http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/fedora/linux/development/rawhide/Spins/i386/iso/ - 2) You have non system files (php) in /usr/local/ : May not match other packages. -

Answer (score 9):

I have been fooling around with this issue a while and I think I solved it doing the following:

installed php mysql using this command in the terminal:

```
dnf install  php-mysqlnd
```

then restarted apache with the following:

```
service httpd restart
```

Comment: thank you so much, this actually worked for me after trying all other answers

Answer (score 0):

**for me, removing php and then installing again worked.**

Before that, I tried installing php-pdo but it did not work. After reinstalling php, I removed php-pdo and php-mysqlnd; and it still worked. crazy!

after each installation/removal, restarted httpd.

Wasted more than an hour and mood on this!

```
sudo dnf -y remove php
sudo dnf -y install php
```